# Dojo internationalization via markup outside of widgets

Tags: internationalization, dojo

Dojo custom widgets can be internationalized via the `_templated` mixin following the steps outlined [here](http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2011/08/25/how-do-i-create-a-dynamic-validating-internationalized-form-in-a-dialog/) and [here](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.7/templated/). Then placeholders within the widget template like this: `${i18n.username}`  are automatically replaced with the appropriate language translation.

**What is the simplest way to do similar nls language substitution outside of a widget?** Ideally, I would like to add an attribute to a tag to have all the placeholders within substituted, including nested tags. Is there some type of container widget that already does this?

Or does Dojo development assume everything will be in a (custom) widget? I need to localize already existing code which doesn't use widgets.

The best solutions I have found so far are:

- Using [dojox.mobile.i18n](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojox/mobile/internationalization.html), which is a "a thin wrapper around dojo.i18n, and has ability to replace strings, such as CDATA or attribute values, in dojo markup." However I'm afraid this is limited to a certain subset of mobile tags/widgets.
- [Disabling automatic parsing and manually searching/replacing the appropriate text before explicitly calling the parser in dojo.addOnLoad()](http://www.webreference.com/programming/dojo/Localizing-Declaratively-Created-Widgets/index.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assumed that the notation in the external html is `${i18n.username}`.This will find any node that has `class="i18nReplace"` and replace the innerHTML of the node.  I didn't test any of this, but I hope you can use it as a starting point.

```
dojo.require("dojo.i18n");
dojo.require("dojo.query");
dojo.requireLocalization("myI18n", "myI18N"); // This will need to be modified to get your i18n files

dojo.addOnLoad(function() {
  var i18n = dojo.i18n.getLocalization("myI18n", "myI18N");
  dojo.query(".i18nReplace").forEach(function(node, index, arr){

      node.innerHTML = dojo.replace(node.innerHTML, { i18n: i18n } );

      // blindly doing this, does not support nested tags.
      // you could add conditional logic to check for children 
      // and if they exist separately process them, otherwise 
      // replace the html.
  });
});
```